# Crystal Reports and WPF handling record selection and parameter

Tags: c#, wpf, crystal-reports

I need to integrate a Crystal Report .rpt file into my WPF application.  Everything is going fine but when I added a report selection to the report it seems to wipe out the parameters.  Here is the code that I am working with;

```
ReportClass r1 = new ReportClass();
r1.FileName = "myReport.rpt";
foreach (var t in r1.Database.Tables)
{
    CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table tb = t as CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.Table;
    tb.LogOnInfo.ConnectionInfo = conInfo;
    tb.ApplyLogOnInfo(tb.LogOnInfo);
}
CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterRangeValue rangeValue = new CrystalDecisions.Shared.ParameterRangeValue();
DateTime sd = (DateTime)StartDatePicker.SelectedDate;
DateTime ed = (DateTime)EndDatePicker.SelectedDate;
rangeValue.StartValue = sd;
rangeValue.EndValue = ed;
r1.SetParameterValue(r1.ParameterFields[0].Name, rangeValue);
string rs = "Correctly formated Record Section Formula"; 
r1.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula = rs;
myReportViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = r1;
```

Now the record selection formula works perfectly.  However it ignores the parameter value.  If the `r1.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula = rs;`is removed then the parameters work correctly.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is there other code?  i don't see you calling Load anywhere, so i assume there is other code.  If there is, are you calling .Refresh()?

Comment: What happens when you replace ReportClass with ReportDocument for the r1 object?

Comment: @Theodosius Von Richthofen There is no more code.  the myReportViewer is the CrystalReportsViewer and setting the ReportSource executes the report

Comment: @Theodosius Von Richthofen changing it to ReportDocument didn't change anything

Comment: why do you need "Correctly formated Record Section Formula"?  this doesn't seem to be a RecordSelectionFormula that would do anything

Comment: Sorry thought I was being clever.  I have a method that will generate the RecordSelectionFormula string based on user entered data.  That works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.  Turns out that `r1.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula = rs;` was over writing the the reports record selection.  Adding this fixed it

```
if (rs != "")
{
    rs = r1.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula + " and " + rs;
}
else
{
    rs = r1.DataDefinition.RecordSelectionFormula;
}
```